# Modify Jupyter Notebook's (ipython kernel) LaTeX rendering of Sympy objects

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter, sympy

I recently started using Jupyter notebook for writing my homework assignments for a Fluid Dynamics class. I use an IPython kernel with Sympy for symbolic computations. Often, I need to print the result of my symbolic calculations as LaTeX output. As an example, see the following code

```
import sympy as s
s.init_printing()
from IPython.display import display
r,t = s.symbols('r,theta')
u_x = r*s.sin(t)
display(u_x)
```

This prints the LaTeX rendering of `$r\sin\theta$` in the cell below the code.
[image: Current Output]
Is there someway I could add `$u_x = $` in front of the output? In this example, the desired output would be

[image]

My purpose is that the output of my `display(u_x)` statement in Jupyter notebook should be like a regular equation in a LaTeX document. The reader should not have to read the code part to understand what quantity that I am displaying in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an arguably slightly less ugly variation of [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213286/), which avoids all the complicated printing stuff.
However, I'm losing the ability to assign an expression at a later time; the expression has to be specified at construction time. But that's probably not a big deal.

Instead of defining a single class, I'm defining a custom class on demand:

```py
import sympy as sp

def named_expression(symbol, expr):

    class NamedExpression(type(expr)):

        def __new__(cls, sym, ex):
            # NB: we don't call the base class' __new__()!
            self = object.__new__(cls)
            if isinstance(sym, sp.Symbol):
                self._symbol = sym
            else:
                self._symbol = sp.Symbol(sym)
            self._expr = ex
            return self

        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            if name in ['_symbol', '_expr', 'as_symbol', 'as_eq']:
                return super().__getattribute__(name)
            return self._expr.__getattribute__(name)

        def as_symbol(self):
            return self._symbol

        def as_eq(self):
            return sp.Eq(self._symbol, self._expr)

    return NamedExpression(symbol, expr)
```

It can be used like this:

```py
u_x = named_expression('u_x', r * sp.sin(t))
```

Or, if you already have a *symbol* named `u_x`, you can overwrite it like this:

```py
u_x = named_expression(u_x, r * sp.sin(t))
```

As before, the equality can be shown like this:

```py
u_x.as_eq()
```

Note that this is not at all specific to IPython, it should work wherever SymPy is available.

Comment: I like both your answers. They provide a comprehensive solution to my problem. I had one concern though. If I have to distribute my Jupyter notebook to others (non-programming type people) then the extra code will be a distraction from the main topic of the notebook. The 4 lines of function that I wrote may be better in this case. What do you think?

Comment: @AmitSingh I wouldn't put any of this directly into the notebook. I would create a Python file in the current directory, e.g. called `utility.py`, and then use it in the notebook with `import utility`. This way you can re-use it in multiple notebooks and it doesn't matter how long the code is. To make it more convenient for readers to find out how it works (if they happen to be interested), you can provide a link to the Python file in a Markdown cell, close to the `import` statement.

Answer (score 3):

After scanning through IPython's `display` module some more, it turns out I can use a function like below

```
from sympy import latex
from IPython.display import display_latex
def disp(idx, symObj):
    eqn = '\\[' + idx + ' = ' + latex(symObj) + '\\]'
    display_latex(eqn,raw=True)
    return
```

Now, `disp('u_x',u_x)` gives the desired output.

[image: Correct output]

Answer (score 2):

I just came up with one (admittedly quite ugly) way to do it, by creating a custom class:

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.printing.pretty.stringpict import prettyForm

class NamedExpression(sp.Expr):

    def __init__(self, name, expr=None, **kwargs):
        self._symbol = sp.Symbol(name, **kwargs)
        self._expr = expr

    def assign(self, expr):
        self._expr = expr

    def as_symbol(self):
        return self._symbol

    def as_eq(self):
        if self._expr is None:
            raise RuntimeError('No expression available')
        return sp.Eq(self._symbol, self._expr)

    def _print_myself(self, printer):
        return _print_function(self, printer)

    _sympystr = _sympyrepr = _latex = _print_myself

    def _pretty(self, printer):
        return prettyForm(_print_function(self, printer))

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in ['_symbol', '_expr', 'assign', 'as_symbol', 'as_eq',
                    '_pretty', '_sympystr', '_sympyrepr', '_latex']:
            return super().__getattribute__(name)
        expr = self._expr
        if expr is not None:
            return expr.__getattribute__(name)
        return self._symbol.__getattribute__(name)


def _print_function(obj, printer):
    expr = obj._expr
    what = obj._symbol if expr is None else expr
    return printer.doprint(what)
```

With this class, you can create your symbol like this:

```py
u_x = NamedExpression('u_x')
```

You can use this in SymPy expressions and it will be displayed like a normal symbol.

At some point, you can assign something to this symbol:

```py
u_x.assign(r * sp.sin(t))
```

After that, you can again use it in SymPy expressions and it will behave like the assigned expression.

If you want to display the definition, just do

```py
u_x.as_eq()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
s.init_session()
```

right after the import of sympy.

Then, simply putting

```
u_x
```

in a cell will render properly, without the need to call display.

Comment: Thanks for replying @PierredeBuyl. I forgot to add that line in my question but I already use `s.init_printing()` in my real code. I have edited my question now. But the original problem still remains. Instead of just rendering the content of `u_x` in LaTeX I would like to see something like `u_x = <content of u_x>` as the output. Also, not using display prints `Out[<output number>]` in front of the output which `display()` does not.

Comment: What is your version of Python, sympy, jupyter, IPython?

Comment: I am sorry I did not mention it earlier. I have now added that information to the question.

Comment: Ok, I thought there was a display issue. If you want to show the relation "u_x = r sin(theta)", you must define it as an equality: `rel = s.Equality(y, r*s.sin(t))` with `y = s.Symbol('y')`. If you ask for `rel = s.Equality(u_x, r*s.sin(t))` after having defined `u_x`, sympy will simply return "True". I hope this is what you asked, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But it is not exactly what I had in mind. Please see my answer below to see the kind of output I expect.

Comment: I see. This is unusual of course :-) The usage I have seen the most is to use plain latex for the "narrative" (also in a notebook, using markdown cells with embedded latex) and use the code only for the parts that require a computation.

Comment: True, that is the most common way to use it perhaps. I export my notebooks to a LaTeX document. In the final document if some equation does not have a left hand side then it is not clear what is quantity that the equation represents unless the reader understands the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been puttering with a somewhat different approach that generates this kind of output directly from assignment statements. I call this `display math operation` or `dmo` for short. You can make calls such as `dmo(p=a*b/c**2)` and get the typeset output `p=...` displayed in Jupyter notebooks.

Along with this I am also working on how to extend sympy functions more generally to show what operations are done. I have working examples for differentiation and integration. I hope to have time to look into how to embed this in sympy, rather than bolt it on.

You can try the examples in mybinder: [image: Binder] The git repository is https://github.com/gutow/Easy_Pretty_Math. Please put suggestions and issues in the git repository [issues](https://github.com/gutow/Easy_Pretty_Math/issues).